# Is there a quick way to switch roles using aws-google-auth?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, google-authentication

I have multiple roles in AWS and have to switch between them multiple times a day.
Can you please suggest a good solution without doing the entire authentication cycle?

Comment: How are you using these roles? Are you using the Management Console, the AWS CLI or is this in code?

Comment: I am using with Cli

Answer (score 1):

You can store multiple roles in the `~/.aws/credentials` file. These can be activated via the AWS CLI by using `--profile`.

You can also put roles in specific profiles and the AWS CLI will assume them from a base set of credentials.

See:

- [Configuration and Credential File Settings - AWS Command Line Interface](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-files.html)
- [Using an IAM Role in the AWS CLI - AWS Command Line Interface](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-role.html)